# recursive function explained python (what is this part doing?)

Tags: python, recursion, big-o, array-merge

```
def merge_sort(a):
    if len(a)<=1:
        return a
    left = merge_sort(a[:len(a)//2])
    //print('this is left step {}'.format(left))
    right = merge_sort(a[len(a)//2:])
    //print('this is right step {}'.format(right))
    return merge(left, right)
```

i understand algebraic recursive functions i understand how it works.

what i dont understand is how `merge_sort(a[len(a)//2:])`
is getting just one number from the passed in list called 'a' (i have a def create_random_array that passes in  random list of numbers ).

my thinking was that it would first split the list in half-witch I could see in my print function, then it would split it again , and again until there is only one that can then be compared.

how does `merge_sort(a[len(a)//2:])` work

**other part of the code that might be useful to understand my mess**

```
def create_array(size = 5, max = 10):
    from random import randint
    return [randint(0,max) for _ in range(size)]



def merge(a,b):
    c = []
    a_idx = 0
    b_idx = 0
    print(a[a_idx])
    print(b[b_idx])
    while a_idx<len(a) and b_idx<len(b):
        if a[a_idx]<b[b_idx]:
            c.append(a[a_idx])
            a_idx+=1
        else:
            c.append(b[b_idx])
            b_idx+=1
    if a_idx==len(a):
        c.extend(b[b_idx:])
    else:
        c.extend(a[a_idx:])
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... then it would split it again , and again until there is only one that can then be compared.

Yes, because at some point, after halving (and halving, and halving ...) your list then it will call `merge_sort` with a list of just one item.

And the first thing that function does is this:

```
def merge_sort(a):
    if len(a)<=1:
        return a
```

That is, a list of just one item is returned as is (rather than being halved).

Comment: so it will half over and over again until there is only length 1 and then print a?

Comment: @anthonypizarro No ... it will return `a` to the caller (to be merged with the other half) and so on recursively.